# Combine row values into character vector by condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame where values are repeated in `col1`.

```
col1 <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C")
col2 <- c(1995, 1997, 1999, 2000, 2005)

df <- data.frame(col1, col2)
```

I want to combine values in `col2` that correspond to the same letter in `col1` into one cell, so that `col2` shows a range of values for a particular letter in `col1`. I do this by splitting the data.frame by `col1`, applying `fun`, and binding the split data.frames back together.

```
library(tidyverse)

split_df <- split(df, df$col1)

fun <- function(df) {
  
  if (length(unique(df$col2)) > 1) {
    
    df$col2 <- paste(min(df$col2),
                     max(df$col2),
                     sep = "-")
    
    df <- distinct(df)
    
  }
  
  return(df)
}

split_df <- lapply(split_df, fun)

df <- do.call(rbind, split_df)
```

This works, but I am wondering if there is a more intuitive or more efficient solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be the tidyverse, where you can accomplish this a little more succinctly. The basic idea is the same:

```
library(tidyverse)

new.result <- df %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  summarize(
    col2 = ifelse(n() == 1, as.character(col2), paste(min(col2), max(col2), sep = '-'))
  )

  col1  col2     
  <chr> <chr>    
1 A     1995-1997
2 B     1999-2000
3 C     2005
```

A different (but possibly overcomplicated) approach assumes that you have at most two years per grouping. We can pivot the start and end years into their own columns, and then paste them together directly. This requires a little more data transformation but avoids having to check explicitly for groups with 1 year:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = n, values_from = col2) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    vec = list(c(`1`, `2`)),
    col2 = paste(vec[!is.na(vec)], collapse = '-')
  ) %>% 
  select(col1, col2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Base R way using `aggregate` -

```
aggregate(col2~col1, df, function(x)  paste0(unique(range(x)), collapse = '-'))

#  col1      col2
#1    A 1995-1997
#2    B 1999-2000
#3    C      2005
```

Same can also be written with `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>%
  summarise(col2 = paste0(unique(range(col2)), collapse = '-'))
```